# AIO Castle Cavalry - My code is too slow, is there a way I can shorten this?

Tags: python

So I am currently preparing for a competition (Australian Informatics Olympiad) and in the [training hub](http://orac.amt.edu.au/cgi-bin/train/hub.pl), there is a problem in AIO 2018 intermediate called [Castle Cavalry](http://orac.amt.edu.au/cgi-bin/train/problem.pl?set=aio18int&problemid=1033). I finished it:

```
input = open("cavalryin.txt").read()
output = open("cavalryout.txt", "w")
squad = input.split()
total = squad[0]
squad.remove(squad[0])
squad_sizes = squad.copy()
squad_sizes = list(set(squad))
yn = []

for i in range(len(squad_sizes)):
    n = squad.count(squad_sizes[i])

    if int(squad_sizes[i]) == 1 and int(n) == int(total):
        yn.append(1)
    elif int(n) == int(squad_sizes[i]):
        yn.append(1)
    elif int(n) != int(squad_sizes[i]):
        yn.append(2)

ynn = list(set(yn))

if len(ynn) == 1 and int(ynn[0]) == 1:
    output.write("YES")
else:
    output.write("NO")

output.close()
```

I submitted this code and I didn't pass because it was too slow, at 1.952secs. The time limit is 1.000 secs. I wasn't sure how I would shorten this, as to me it looks fine. PLEASE keep in mind I am still learning, and I am only an amateur. I started coding only this year, so if the answer is quite obvious, sorry for wasting your time .

Thank you for helping me out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One performance issue is calling `int()` over and over on the same entity, or on things that are already `int`:

```
if int(squad_sizes[i]) == 1 and int(n) == int(total):
elif int(n) == int(squad_sizes[i]):
elif int(n) != int(squad_sizes[i]):
if len(ynn) == 1 and int(ynn[0]) == 1:
```

But the real problem is your code doesn't work.  And making it faster won't change that.  Consider the input:

```
4
2
2
2
2
```

Your code will output `"NO"` (with missing newline) despite it being a valid configuration.  This is due to your collapsing the squad sizes using `set()` early in your code.  You've thrown away vital information and are only really testing a subset of the data.  For comparison, here's my complete rewrite that I believe handles the input correctly:

```
with open("cavalryin.txt") as input_file:
    string = input_file.read()

total, *squad_sizes = map(int, string.split())

success = True

while squad_sizes:
    squad_size = squad_sizes.pop()

    for _ in range(1, squad_size):
        try:
            squad_sizes.remove(squad_size)  # eliminate n - 1 others like me
        except ValueError:
            success = False
            break

    else:  # no break
        continue

    break

with open("cavalryout.txt", "w") as output_file:

    print("YES" if success else "NO", file=output_file)
```

Note that I convert all the input to `int` early on so I don't have to consider that issue again.  I don't know whether this will meet AIO's timing constraints.

Comment: I tried your version of the code, and it got 28/100. It still is too slow, and most of the judgements were: "Time limit exceeded. This may be due to an infinite loop/recursion, or your algorithm may be too slow for this subtask" I think i will try to write this program in a different language, though. Thank you anyways!

Answer (score 0):

I can see some things in there that might be inefficient, but the best way to optimize code is to profile it: run it with a profiler and sample data.

You can easily waste time trying to speed up parts that don't need it without having much effect. Read up on the `cProfile` module in the standard library to see how to do this and interpret the output. A profiling tutorial is probably too long to reproduce here.

My suggestions, without profiling,

```
squad.remove(squad[0])
```

Removing the start of a big list is slow, because the rest of the list has to be copied as it is shifted down. (Removing the end of the list is faster, because lists are typically backed by arrays that are overallocated (more slots than elements) anyway, to make .append()s fast, so it only has to decrease the length and can keep the same array.

It would be better to set this to a dummy value and remove it when you convert it to a set (sets are backed by hash tables, so removals are fast), e.g.

```
dummy = object()
squad[0] = dummy  # len() didn't change. No shifting required.
...
squad_sizes = set(squad)
squad_sizes.remove(dummy)  # Fast lookup by hash code.
```

Since we know these will all be strings, you can just use `None` instead of a dummy object, but the above technique works even when your list might contain `None`s.

```
squad_sizes = squad.copy()
```

This line isn't required; it's just doing extra work. The `set()` already makes a shallow copy.

```
n = squad.count(squad_sizes[i])
```

This line might be the real bottleneck. It's effectively a loop inside a loop, so it basically has to scan the whole list for each outer loop. Consider using `collections.Counter` for this task instead. You generate the count table once outside the loop, and then just look up the numbers for each string.

You can also avoid generating the set altogether if you do this. Just use the `Counter` object's keys for your set.

---

Another point unrelated to performance. It's unpythonic to use indexes like `[i]` when you don't need them. A for loop can get elements from an iterable and assign them to variables in one step:

```
from collections import Counter
...
count_table = Counter(squad)

for squad_size, n in count_table.items():
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can collect all occurences of the preferred number for each knight in a dictionary. 
Then test if the number of knights with a given preferred number is divisible by that number.

```
with open('cavalryin.txt', 'r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

# convert to int
list_int = [int(a) for a in lines]

#initialise counting dictionary: key: preferred number, item: empty list to collect all knights with preferred number. 
collect_dict = {a:[] for a in range(1,1+max(list_int[1:]))}

print(collect_dict)

# loop though list, ignoring first entry. 
for a in list_int[1:]:
    collect_dict[a].append(a)

# initialise output
out='YES'

for key, item in collect_dict.items():

    # check number of items with preference for number is divisilbe 
    # by that number
    if item: # if list has entries:
        if (len(item) % key) > 0:
            out='NO'
            break

with open('cavalryout.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write(out)
```